# ORACLE - to subquery or not to subquery?

Tags: oracle, join, subquery

I have the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM KRIM_ENTITY_NM_T KE
    WHERE TO_NUMBER(KE.PREFIX_NM) >= 5 OR
    lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
    lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%' OR
    lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
    lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%';
-- result = 712

 SELECT MBR_ID FROM KRIM_GRP_MBR_T KG WHERE KG.MBR_TYP_CD = 'P' AND KG.GRP_ID = '2012';
-- result = 691
```

The 2 tables are related via MBR_ID and ENTITY_ID
`KG.MBR_ID = KE.ENTITY_ID`

Per the result `count` - there is a delta of 21.

Question:  What is the best way to get a listing of ENTITY_IDs that do not show up in the SELECT MBR_ID query?

Would the best approach be a sub-query or JOIN?
Also I'm thinking that EXISTS IN OR NOT IN would be needed here.  Just having trouble with putting those 2 approaches together.

(I'm not worried about performance, I just need to run this once for some clean-up work and throw it away).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not exists` or `not in` would both work, but maybe you're fooled by the 'or's in the query. Because of operator precedence, you have to add some parentheses:

Using `in`, embedding the second query exactly as you wrote it:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM KRIM_ENTITY_NM_T KE
    WHERE 
    ( TO_NUMBER(KE.PREFIX_NM) >= 5 OR
      lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
      lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%' OR
      lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
      lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%'
    ) AND
    ENTITYID NOT IN (
      SELECT MBR_ID FROM KRIM_GRP_MBR_T KG WHERE KG.MBR_TYP_CD = 'P' AND KG.GRP_ID = '2012'
    )
```

Using `exists`:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID FROM KRIM_ENTITY_NM_T KE
    WHERE 
    ( TO_NUMBER(KE.PREFIX_NM) >= 5 OR
      lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
      lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%' OR
      lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
      lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%'
    ) AND
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM KRIM_GRP_MBR_T KG 
      WHERE KG.MBR_TYP_CD = 'P' AND 
        KG.GRP_ID = '2012' AND
        KG.MBRID = KE.ENTITYID
    )
```

Comment: Spot on!  Thank you!

Comment: Be careful of the `NOT IN` approach if `KRIM_GRP_MBR_T.MBR_ID` allows null values.  It will not work if there are any nulls.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to do this come immediately to mind:

You can use an OUTER JOIN and look for the NULLs:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID
  FROM KRIM_ENTITY_NM_T KE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MBR_ID
                     FROM KRIM_GRP_MBR_T
                     WHERE MBR_TYP_CD = 'P' AND
                           GRP_ID = '2012') kg
    ON kg.MBR_ID = KE.ENTITY_ID
  WHERE (TO_NUMBER(KE.PREFIX_NM) >= 5 OR
         lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
         lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%' OR
         lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
         lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%') AND
        kb.MBR_ID IS NULL
```

Or you can use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID
  FROM KRIM_ENTITY_NM_T KE
  WHERE (TO_NUMBER(KE.PREFIX_NM) >= 5 OR
         lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
         lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%' OR
         lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
         lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%') AND
        KE.ENTITY_ID NOT IN (SELECT MBR_ID
                               FROM KRIM_GRP_MBR_T KG
                               WHERE KG.MBR_TYP_CD = 'P' AND
                                     KG.GRP_ID = '2012')
```

Personally, I've found that the OUTER JOIN method performs better, but others have said the opposite, so test and determine what works best at your site.

### EDIT

You can also use the MINUS set operator:

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID
  FROM KRIM_ENTITY_NM_T KE
  WHERE TO_NUMBER(KE.PREFIX_NM) >= 5 OR
        lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
        lower(KE.TITLE_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%' OR
        lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%professor%' OR
        lower(KE.SUFFIX_NM) LIKE '%senior lecturer%'
MINUS
SELECT MBR_ID AS ENTITY_ID
  FROM KRIM_GRP_MBR_T KG
  WHERE KG.MBR_TYP_CD = 'P' AND
        KG.GRP_ID = '2012'
```

Comment: Performance depends on many factors. I've found either solution to work better depending on the circumstances, although I never really figured out what those circumstances are. :-p  I would initially go with `NOT IN`, or `NOT EXISTS`, because I think those convey the purpose better, and try the left join if performance is really bad. But it's good to have that left join option in your toolkit too. :-)